# trouble with creating Ubuntu desktop on WSL2

Tags: system-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In order to run OpenFOAM CFD software, I need to create an Ubuntu desktop on Windows Subsystem for Linux2.  I found a guide on how to do this using VcXsrv, on this link:  https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-with-gui-and-sound-on-wsl2-611cdb3dde9d

I got all the way to the bottom, where I double-click on the Ubuntu shortcut; then this message appears:  "Another Xserver is already running"  It shows a path to the log file, which states:  "Xming or Cygwin/X is already running display monitor:0"

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Follow-up to my question: In task manager, I saw a line with "Xming". So I stopped that process, and again tried to open the Ubuntu desktop. This time, it opened, but then after a few minutes, it disappeared with a "system crashed" message. So the problem is related to the Xming server, but there is more to it than just stopping it. I need help!

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1231153)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1413871/edit) by clicking on the **Edit** below your question and add all additional "Follow-up to your questions".